# How to display one value for a one column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this,

```
|FailCount| TC Name| Hierarchy | RC | Category|
```

I am trying to sum up FailCount and total number of TC Name is displayed for every unique Hierarchy.
I have a search query which does that:

```
select sum(FailCount) as 'Failure Count', count(*) as 'TC Count', `Hierarchy` from FailReport_Table 
where Category in ('Category1,Category2') and OWNER = 'Raja' 
group by `Hierarchy` order by `Failure Count` desc";
```

so this will return me something like

```
|Failure Count | TC Count|  Hierarchy|
|12            |      143|  abc.fc.nf|
|1             |      134|    ghjs.sk|
```

along with this table I want additional field as RC. Each unique Hierarchy can have different RC and I want to display any one RC for that Hierarchy.

I tried including RC in my previous query like this, but it didn't work.

```
select sum(FailCount) as 'Failure Count', count(*) as 'TC Count', `Hierarchy`, RC from FailReport_Table 
where Category in ('Category1,Category2') and OWNER = 'Raja' 
group by `Hierarchy` order by `Failure Count` desc";
```

i am new to SQL.

Comment: why do you have double asterisks around `RC`?  Was that supposed to be bold text?

Comment: Thats just to highligh...nothing special :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display any one RC for a given hierarchy then you can make use of MAX() function to get you the max_rc_field as follows

```
    select  sum(FailCount) as 'Failure Count'
          , count(*)       as 'TC Count'
          , `Hierarchy`
          , MAX(RC)        as RC
      from FailReport_Table 
     where Category in ('Category1,Category2') 
       and OWNER = 'Raja' 
     group by `Hierarchy` 
     order by `Failure Count` desc";
```